# Android: SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview, z-order

I have SurfaceView with `setZOrderOnTop(true)` .This flag is needed for the transparent SurfaceView's background during the drawing process.

How can I display any View in front of it?

Answer (score 0):

SurfaceViews are not designed to be composited with other views. As described in the doc for [setZOrderOnTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderOnTop%28boolean%29), once you set this mode, none of the other window contents will be visible on top of the SurfaceView.

If you want to do compositing, you will have to do it yourself, off-screen, then draw the results into the SurfaceView.

Comment: How can I draw the results into the SurfaceView?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, that still work.
But if you use a RelativeLayout, it will be ugly.

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.applicationtest.MainActivity" >
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#44444444"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
            android:text="ttttttttttttttttttttt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:text="ttttttttttttttttttttt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:text="ttttttttttttttttttttt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The WallPaperService are usung SurfaceView.
So there is  no reason that no view can't be on the top of SurfaceView...(I guess??)